# How to fetch data from coinmarketcap's api

Tags: javascript, database, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from coinmarketcap and the error I get back in the console log is:

GET https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=(API key hidden) 400 (Bad Request)

I have a feeling it's the url variable that I have created that is causing the problem but I'm not entirely sure.

I changed the value of the url variable to a random api from jsonplaceholders.com and that seemed to work so that is why I'm thinking what's causing the problem is the url value.

```
let url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info",
  qString = "?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=" + apiKey + "&start=1&limit=5&convert=USD";

fetch(url + qString, { mode: "no-cors" })
  .then(resp => {
    return resp.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

I expect to receive info on the cryptocurrency and for the console log to display it

Comment: What does your apiKey look like? Do you need to call `encodeURIComponent` on it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @Omn It's the API key that coinmarketcap gave me. In the documentation, it didn't say that I needed to call that so probably not.

Comment: Setting `mode: 'no-cors'` tells `fetch` that you aren't doing anything that requires CORS which suppresses CORS related error messages. Since you want to read data from a remote origin, you **do** need permission from CORS, so that will just break things.

Comment: The "This question already exists" link has been "removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation." and is no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

Please confirm your api query string data.

I checked coinMarketCap documentation and found the sample api url as below

https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info?id=1,2,10

updated:

One of the api is look like your intention.

https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?sort=market_cap&start=1&limit=10&cryptocurrency_type=tokens&convert=USD,BTC

updated solution :

You forgot to add "&" after api key and you need to remove BTC.

```
    let url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest", 
    qString = "?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=" + apiKey + "&sort=market_cap&start=1&limit=10&cryptocurrency_type=tokens&convert=USD";
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it. I added that api and the error changed to this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized). Heres what I changed it to ```let url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest",
  qString =
    "?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=" +
    apiKey +
    "sort=market_cap&start=1&limit=10&cryptocurrency_type=tokens&convert=USD,BTC";```

Comment: please find the updated solution based on your comment.

Comment: I removed BTC from the query string due to getting bad request (Your plan is limited to 1 convert options).     You can also try it out in the postman/chrome rest client is fine for previewing api response with respective of your input.

Comment: Thanks for recommending postman. I entered ```sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=${uri}&sort=market_cap&start=1&limit=10&cryptocurrency_type=tokens&convert=USD``` into postman and was able to receive the data but when I pasted that into my fetch() the console still came out with an error "404 not found"

Comment: You can copied a whole url including api key from postman and paste it on the fetch url and try. Its seems like some values are not appending in your url is not properly. Are you having any variable like "**uri**"?

Comment: I confirmed @AlwinJose solution is working for my CMC's Basic Plan (Free) API. Thanks!